# Is there a way to get a unique hash code from an arry of colors?

Tags: c#, arrays, hash, compare, unique

I am trying to get a unique hash code from an array of colors. The code must be unique according to the way the array is set. Eventually I would like to use this hash code to compare to another hash code generated from anothe (To check that both of them have the same colors in the same index).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Test
    {
        public Color[] GridMap { get; set; }

        private Color[] ColorSet
        {
            get
            {
                var colors = new[]
                {
                    Color.Aquamarine,
                    Color.Azure,
                    Color.Red,
                    Color.Blue
                };
                return colors;
            }
        }

        public Test()
        {
            GridMap = new Color[24];
            var random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < GridMap.Length; i++)
            {
                GridMap[i] = ColorSet[random.Next(0,3)];
            }
        }

        public ulong GetUniqueCodeFromGridMap()
        {
            // Dont Know how to implement this yet !
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to use `Enumerable<Color>.SequenceEqual` like

```
bool b = colors1.SequenceEqual(colors2);
```

If you really want to create a hash code, You can write a code like

```
var bytes = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue }
                .Select(x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x.ToArgb()))
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .ToArray();
var hashCode = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
```

Now you should compare `hashCodes`.... ( again you can use `SequenceEqual` )

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'll try them both just to check how they work, maybe set a timer to check the most optimal way to compare these arrays, but the first method looks more simpler and less expensive than the other. Thanks for pointing the first solution out !